# How can I properly enqueue tags <link> in WordPress to use with Web Components?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

The Chrome browser supports `Web Components` and I would like to add a number of them in WordpPress pages, but using the queuing mechanism as in the case of the functions `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` for scripts and styles.

Anyone out there can help me?

If there is no ready function to do this a suggestion of how to implement this in PHP would be welcome.

Comment: There is no enqueuing feature for link tags, generally you would just add them to your theme's header directly, or output them in a function hooked to wp_head.

Comment: Ok @Otto but I need a best practice advice to write a Class which extends WP_Dependencies class (from wp-includes/class.wp-dependencies.php) to manage the `<link rel="import" ...>` tag to load a component properly.

Comment: With something like `wp_enqueue_html('my-tabs')` I can manage component load which is referenced somewhere in my plugin or theme code. In this case, the `wp_enqueue_html` function must be render something like `<link rel="import" href="my-tabs.html">` where `my-tabs.html` implements my tabs WEB Component.